# Shadow copy storage space: difference between, and control over, "Used", "Allocated" and "Maximum" (in Windows 7)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, volume-shadow-copy, shadow-copy

Using the **vssadmin list shadowstorage** command in Windows 7, one gets an overview of the disk space related to shadow copies. Typically three values are returned:

- **Used** Shadow Copy Storage space
- **Allocated** Shadow Copy Storage space
- **Maximum** Shadow Copy Storage space

However, I have a hard time to understand the logic/difference between the three.

In particular:

- I see in **System Protection** that I can tune the **Max Usage**, but then where does the **allocated** space comes from and how would it be different of the **used** space?
- And if the user has the hand on the **allocated** space, how can one assign this value and why then wouldn't the system use the maximum space available?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of these values is as follows :

- **Maximum** : The amount of space that can be allocated
- **Allocated** : The amount that is currently allocated that can grow up to
  the Maximum
- **Used** : The amount that is used within the Allocated area.

Numerically, we have the following inequality :

```
Used ≤ Allocated ≤ Maximum
```

All values can grow up to the Maximum. Manual intervention is required
to increase the Maximum by using the
[vssadmin resize shadowstorage command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin-resize-shadowstorage).

Comment: Yes, this is how I understand the terms. But I still don't understand the difference between "used" and "allocated" because those terms seem synonymous to me. Could it be that "used" is the amount of data stored and "allocated" is the amount of space those data take up on the filesystem in terms of blocks (same as when one looks at the properties of a file)? Also is the "maximum" space set completely reserved and inaccessible to the user even if not completely used or allocated?

Comment: I agree with your formulations. About whether the Maximum space is reserved, this does not seem to be the case. Microsoft's documentation does not answer this question, but user posts say so : [link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/fc2c897c-9253-4560-a71c-f729a1116f59/failed-to-create-a-shadow-copy-volume-shadow-copy-service-error?forum=winserverfiles) and [link2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7a0bd1b0-ed26-4172-879b-16a22073d855/does-shadow-copies-reserve-the-space-its-setup-with-so-it-cant-be-used-by-users?forum=winserver8gen).

Comment: ... It stands to logic, that if the Maximum was reserved, there would be no reason for not allocating immediately all of it.

Comment: So, according to this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd348398(v=msdn.10), 'allocated' means 'reserved'. That was the missing piece for my understanding. Mabe you wish to edit your answer accordingly and I make it as accepted?

Comment: Your article says exactly what is written in my answer, that 'allocated' does not mean 'reserved'. Quote: "Lists the volume shadow storage space **currently in use**, the space that is **reserved for future use (labeled as allocated)**, and the **maximum space that might be dedicated**."

Comment: Well, yes, it says  that "**reserved** (for future use) [is labeled as] **allocated**"... So 'allocated' means 'reserved'. How do you understand it differently?

Comment: I understand that what is allocated is reserved and can be used for shadow storage. The allocation can increase up to the maximum. "Allocated" is used in the context of a disk to mean space/sectors that belong to a file, in this case the shadow storage. The maximum is not allocated, so the allocation might fail if not enough free space is available on the disk, which is what I believe happened in my above [link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/fc2c897c-9253-4560-a71c-f729a1116f59/failed-to-create-a-shadow-copy-volume-shadow-copy-service-error?forum=winserverfiles).

Comment: This is obtuse to say the least.  My situation is Allocated is a measly 704 MB, but I set Maximum storage space to 40GB (it's a 1TB backup USB drive).

When I run `wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:I: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet` I get this:

A Volume Shadow Copy Service operation error has
occurred: (0x8004231f)
Insufficient storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data.

Comment: Re my earlier post - to not get the error launch as `wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:I: -include:C: -quiet`, namely exclude the -allCritical

Comment: @SKidd: I think you should post your own question with all the details.